# Regexp - match till dot, but without last character

Tags: php, regex

I have big files with multiple entries like

```
car.bus.bike:
car.bus.bike.vehicle
car.bus.bike
_car.bus.bike
'car.bus.bike'
```

I want to match and replace `car.bus.bike` without matching last `:` or do not match where there is `.vehicle` or where matched is prefixed with anything.

So in the end I want to replace `car.bus.bike` with `cat.mouse.dog` to be like:

```
cat.mouse.dog:
car.bus.bike.vehicle
cat.mouse.dog
_car.bus.bike
'cat.mouse.dog'
```

I had tried with matching till `.`, with `[^-_.]$` but it also matches `:` I tried with positive lookahead `(?=\:)` or negative lookbehind `(?<!_)` but every time it only covers one case.

Comment: Try `\w+(?:\.\w+){2}`, you may even require [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace once only if you pass the `$count` argument equal to `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```sh
(?<!\.)\b\pL\w*(?:\.\w+){2}(?=[':]|$)
```

And replace it with:

```
cat.mouse.dog
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4XHjBC/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\.)`: Assert that we don't have dot at the previous position
- `\b`: Match a word boundary
- `\pL`: Match a unicode letter
- `\w*`: Match 0 or more word characters
- `(?:\.\w+){2}`: Match a dot followed by 1+ word characters. Repeat this group 2 times
- `(?=[':]|$)`: Assert that we have a `;` or `'` or end of line at the next position

For PHP use this regex:

```sh
/(?<!\.)\b\pL\w*(?:\.\w+){2}(?=[':]|$)/mu
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the string must begin with a letter or single quote. If we are confident that if it begins with a single quote it will end with one as well we can substitute `'cat.mouse.dog'` for a match of the following regular expression.

```
^'?\p{L}+(?:\.\p{L}+){2}(?!\.vehicle$)[.:']?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KPDELC/1)

This expression can be broken down as follows (and/or hover the cursor over each part of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function).

```
^             # match beginning of string
'?            # optionally match a single quote
\p{L}+        # match one or more unicode letters
(?:           # begin non-capture group
  \.\p{L}+    # match a period followed by one or more unicode letters
){2}          # end non-capture group and execute it twice
(?!           # begin negative lookahead
  \.vehicle$  # match '.vehicle' at the end of the string
)             # end negative lookahead
[.:']?        # optionally (?) match one of the three chars in the char class
$             # match end of string
```

If we wish to ensure that the string begins with a single quote if and only if it ends with one as well we need to modify the regular expression. One way of doing that is to insert the following *positive lookahead* after the beginning-of-string anchor (`^`).

```
(?='[^']+'$|[^']+$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z2kdmH/1)

(At the link I set the multiline flag and changed the two instances of `[^']` to `[^'\n]` in order to demonstrate which of several strings were matched by the expression.)

To restrict matches of letters to English letters replace `\p{L}` with `[a-z]` and set the case-indifferent flag (e.g., add `(?i)` at the beginning).